# Prometheus - Inhibit warning alert when same alert is in critical

Tags: prometheus-alertmanager

I tried inhibiting the alerts so same alert in critical can inhibit warning alert.
The below configs didnt work...Please suggest whats the issue with this config..

```
inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    alertname: Inhibit
    severity: critical
  target_match:
    severity: warning
    alertname: KubePodNotReady
  equal: ['alertname', 'namespace', 'pod', 'prometheus']

inhibit_rules:
- source_match:
    severity: 'critical'
  target_match:
    severity: 'warning'
  equal: ['alertname', 'namespace', 'pod','prometheus']
```

Answer (score 0):

The below config works for me.

```
inhibit_rules:
 - source_match:
       severity: critical
       alertname: KubePodNotReady
   target_match:
       severity: warning
       alertname: KubePodNotReady
   equal: ['namespace', 'pod', 'prometheus']
```